# How to add class to navigation item by route path

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

i'm working on a vue.js project and in my navigation component there are multiple router-links within li element like below

```
<li
   class="m-menu__item m-menu__item--active"
   aria-haspopup="true"
   id="dashboard"
   @click="toggleMenu('dashboard')"
 >
 <router-link to="/dashboard" class="m-menu__link">
     <i class="m-menu__link-icon flaticon-line-graph"></i>
        <span class="m-menu__link-title">
        <span class="m-menu__link-wrap">
             <span class="m-menu__link-text">{{ $t("Dashboard") }}</span>
        </span>
        </span>
 </router-link>
</li>
```

what i want to do is add new class to li element by router-link path. using a watch property i could get the current route and rest of the work seems hard to me.
watch property is like below

```
watch:{
    $route (to, from){
       console.log(to.path);
       $('[to="'+path+'"]').parent().addClass('yourClass'); // i tried this way and it didn't work
      }
},
```

*Note that i cant do it by click event because i can navigate through the links using dashboard too.
please give me a way to do this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could do it like below.

```
<li
    class="m-menu__item"
    :class="checkIsPathAndRoutePathSame('/dashboard') ? 'm-menu__item--active' : ''"
    id="dashboard"
    @click="toggleMenu('dashboard')"
>
  <router-link to="/dashboard" class="m-menu__link">
             
  </router-link>
</li>

data() {
    return {
        currentRoute: ''
    };
},
watch:{
     $route (to, from){
          this.currentRoute = to.path;
      }
},
mounted() {
    this.currentRoute = this.$route.path;},
methods: {
    checkIsPathAndRoutePathSame(path){
        if(this.currentRoute === path){
             return true;
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a class to your active route link, just use the `active-class` or `exact-active-class` property https://router.vuejs.org/api/#active-class :

```
<router-link
  to="/dashboard"
  class="m-menu__link"
  active-class="yourClass"
>
</router-link>
```

Notice that you can render the `<route-link>` component as a `<li>` element, so just add li classes to router-link component

**Edit**

```
<li
   class="m-menu__item m-menu__item--active"
   aria-haspopup="true"
   id="dashboard"
   @click="toggleMenu('dashboard')"
   :class="{ 'my-active-class': isDashboardActive }"
 >
 <router-link to="/dashboard" class="m-menu__link">
     <i class="m-menu__link-icon flaticon-line-graph"></i>
        <span class="m-menu__link-title">
        <span class="m-menu__link-wrap">
             <span class="m-menu__link-text">{{ $t("Dashboard") }}</span>
        </span>
        </span>
 </router-link>
</li>
```

And in you component JS you have 2 options:

```js
data: () => ({
  isDashboardActive: false
}),
watch:{
    $route (to, from){
       console.log(to.path);
       this.isDashboardActive = true
    }
},
```

or this

```js
computed: {
  // if you use computed, you can remove data and watch
  isDashboardActive () {
    return this.$route.path === '/dashboard'
  }
},
```

Another option to keep the same html structure, relying on active-class:

```
<router-link
   class="m-menu__item m-menu__item--active"
   aria-haspopup="true"
   id="dashboard"
   @click="toggleMenu('dashboard')"
   to="/dashboard"
   active-class="yourClass"
 >
 <a class="m-menu__link">
     <i class="m-menu__link-icon flaticon-line-graph"></i>
        <span class="m-menu__link-title">
        <span class="m-menu__link-wrap">
             <span class="m-menu__link-text">{{ $t("Dashboard") }}</span>
        </span>
        </span>
 </a>
</li>
```

Comment: thank you for answering, But the thing is i'm not allowed to change the HTML structure.

Comment: OK I proposed a couple other options

Comment: Thank you. i think i found a way much likely you're 2nd answer.